# How to debug push notifications on iOS 7 or iOS 8 device?

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, apple-push-notifications

I have a problem with voip push notifications not arriving sometimes to the app delegate and I want to track where the problem is.

I enabled push logging on the device as described in Apple's technical note from here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG23

I sent few push notifications (which arrived) to test the logs but there are no logs containing any push notification info in

```
/Users/[username]/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<devicename>/PersistentConnection/
```

..folder containing my app bundle identifier nor anything with `apsd` (I tried both spotlight and manually search files).

I see documentation was updated last time 2014-10-01, after iOS 8 was released and I wonder if it is outdated anyway? I see small note:

> Note: On iOS  6.x, push logs will not be written to the device console.
>   They are only available by syncing the device with iTunes (r.
>   12575868).

Is this also the case with iOS 7 and 8?

Which files should I look into (there are plenty of files updated in PersistenConnection folder every time I connect device by cable)?

What am I doing wrong? Is there a more convenient / automated tool to collect this type of logs?